# Is there any example where $\lim x_n=0$, and there exists a subsequence $\{s_{k _j} \}$ such that $\lim_{j\to \infty} s_{k_j}$ exists?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find an example where $\lim x_n=0$, and there exists a subsequence $\{s_{k_j} \}$ such that $\lim_{j\to \infty} s_{k_j}$ exists, but $\sum x_n$ still diverges.($s_k$
is a partial sum of the series and $s_{k_j}$
is a subsequence of $s_k$)

I have no idea for solving this.
I know if the series diverges, partial sum of the series diverges too.

Then How can I find a subsequence $\{s_{k_j} \}$ such that $\lim_{j\to \infty} s_{k_j}$ exists.

pleas give me some hints.

Comment: What is $s_k$$_j$ ?

Comment: oh sorry. $s_k$ is a partial sum of the series and $s_k$$_j$ is a subsequence of $s_k$

Comment: That clarification should be edited into the body of the question, Damon, not just put into the comments.

Comment: This question is so poorly written, I vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(x_n)=(1,-1,\frac 1 2 ,\frac 1 2,-\frac 1  2,-\frac 1  2 ,\frac 13 ,\frac 13 ,\frac 13 , -\frac 1 3, -\frac 1 3 -\frac 1 3,...)$ is such a sequence. There is a subsequence of partial sums which has the constant value $0$ and there is a subsequence of partial sums which has the constant value $1$.

[The $n-$th block is $\frac 1 n $ repeated $n-$times followed by $-\frac 1 n $ repeated $n-$times].

Answer (score 1):

Here's another problem that will let you generate a bunch of such sequences:

> Take any differentiable function $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$.
>
> Define $s_n = \sin(f(n))$.  Then $x_n = s_n-s_{n-1} \to 0$ but given any $L \in [-1,1]$, there is a subsequence of $s_n$ that converges to $L$.